# Amazing music videos for sound recordists

Tags: music, concrete, video, recording

These guys always make epic videos but I thought it would be of interest to most of you. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MejbOFk7H6c The pure scale and effort in production for this is mind blowing. If anybody else has any other good vids involving involving live sound effects used in music or a concrete style or element please post them up.